# It is possible to setup two factor authantication for a local account (non online microsoft account), on Window 10?

Tags: windows, multi-factor-authentication

For now, I don't want to use an "online" Microsoft account. My laptop have a fingerprint reader/scanner. I was wondering if it is possible somehow to use a password in combination with the fingerprint reader in order to authenticate my "local" user account. If not possible, is there any other way to have a two factor or multi factor authentication method with a local account?

Regards.

Comment: Have you looked at YubiKey?  https://www.yubico.com/products/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=pd%3Asearch&utm_campaign=ca_b2c_leadgen_google_sem_brand&utm_content=&gclid=cj0kcqia0-6abhdmarisafvdqv9bgrhcbjqu3mggfxl9rav5t9ojui7m3ehdd4oxc2ltqufvxocsgd4aahdhealw_wcb

Comment: Yes I know about yubikey and the likes, but that requires some sort of online "something" I want to keep everything local.